# How can I wire the speaker given in this schematic? Does the light green addition show it correctly?

Tags: amplifier, wiring, speakers

[image]

Taken from [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PPQ6qnrWok)

Will it work correctly with the speaker connected as shown in green?

Comment: Does the video author state that this circuit will drive a loudspeaker. I don't think so and I don't think it will. It is not powerful enough to drive the low resistance of the speaker. You migth hear something from it if held up against your ear.

Comment: @Transistor because of the 1K resistor between emitter and ground? What if we ignore the values of resistors and just completed the circuit by adding a loudspeaker to it, where would it go? Where the light green lines are? Thank you!

Comment: @AlexC It would not make much sense to connect a heavy load such as a speaker to a circuit  not intended to drive heavy loads. You can't ignore the resistor values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Justme. I will absolutely adjust values around the circuit once it is complete. If anyone could confirm how the speaker would be connected and I can move on to tailoring it.

Comment: @AlexC, that circuit is a "small-signal" amplifier or a "pre-amplifier" for an audio system. It will boost the signal a little bit but if you want to drive a loudspeaker you need a "power amplifier" stage or circuit. You can't just "ignore" components. The design of an amplifier requires careful attention to *every* component and their value calcultations. You need to study these things starting at fundementals and building up on your previous knowledge.

Comment: @Transistor, I appreciate the advice. But I also find it humorous how hard it is to get a simple answer, IF there was a speaker, where would it go and how. I understand that this is a small signal amplifier and that it is just a beginning of the learning path. However, this is meant to help my son's grade 7 science project. It is about comparing various amplifiers, starting with the MOST SIMPLE one. We are not after quality. We are after showing progression of quality improvement as we explore single transistor, IC based and then a pre-assembled board.

Comment: "*However, this is meant to help my son's grade 7 science project.*" That context is missing from the question. I'll post an answer. Regarding a simple answer, it's probably because anyone with experience just wouldn't try to do it. It's a bit like, "I've got a motor out of a battery powered toy and I want to drive my motorbike with it." You wouldn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Strictly speaking, because C2 is a polarised type with a positive and negative terminal the polarity matters. It's negative terminal should be kept more negative than the positive (or with zero difference).

Since the positive terminal will normally be at about half the supply voltage (4.5 V or so) that means that the green connection is pulling the negative terminal higher than the positive.

The right way to connect it is shown in red.

In practice C2 might never fail with the 9 V supply.

Answer (score 1):

There may some missing context with your question. But from what you've asked so far, you'd just hook up the speaker to the positive terminal of your battery and the other end to the mentioned capacitor C2. The speaker at the end of the day is basically a giant resistor that only has a few ohms of resistance.

Comment: K, so you are confirming that hooking up positive terminal of speaker to the positive rail and negative to the C2 capacitor? The way the light green is on the schematic pic?